# puppet iptables string rate limiting

Tags: iptables, puppet, asterisk

Does puppet firewall support the string module? I need help to implement the following iptables rules in puppet but can't find any documentation or examples on how to do this.

```
 iptables -I INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 5060 -m string --string "User-Agent: VaxSIPUserAgent" --algo bm --to 65535 -j DROP 
 iptables -I INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 5060 -m string --string "User-Agent: friendly-scanner" --algo bm --to 65535 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable 
 iptables -I INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 5060 -m string --string "REGISTER sip:" --algo bm -m recent --set --name VOIP --rsource 
 iptables -I INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 5060 -m string --string "REGISTER sip:" --algo bm -m recent --update --seconds 60 --hitcount 12 --rttl --name VOIP --rsource -j DROP 
 iptables -I INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 5060 -m string --string "INVITE sip:" --algo bm -m recent --set --name VOIPINV --rsource 
 iptables -I INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 5060 -m string --string "INVITE sip:" --algo bm -m recent --update --seconds 60 --hitcount 12 --rttl --name VOIPINV --rsource -j DROP 
 iptables -I INPUT -p udp -m hashlimit --hashlimit 6/sec --hashlimit-mode srcip,dstport --hashlimit-name tunnel_limit -m udp --dport 5060 -j ACCEPT 
 iptables -I INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 5060 -j DROP
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is example, but you have to download puppet-firewall first

```
firewall { 'your_rule':
    string => "INVITE sip:",
    string_algo => "bm"
  }
```

Comment: The server is already under puppet control, I was just wondering how to write the manifests.

Comment: I get "invalid parameter string"

Comment: My puppet version is 3.8.7

Comment: It needed puppet 5

Answer (score 0):

Puppet itself does not have a resource like iptables/firewall out of the box.

To mange iptables/firewall you can use a [off. module from puppet labs](https://forge.puppet.com/puppetlabs/firewall)

Alternative you can build your own module (which handels your iptables config) with [augeas](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/types/augeas.html) as [resource type](http://augeas.net/)